# Punishment for masturbation

Tags: punishment, forgiveness, masturbation

I want to know what is the punishment for masturbation in Islam? It was done by someone close to me to avoid falling into more evil acts such as fornication and zina. The person cannot get married due to psychological problems.
I read ayat of quran telling us to guard our private parts except from spouse or right hand.
Can anyone assist me with finding the punishment in the hereafter and are the people who masturbate cursed by Allah?
Is there any forgiveness.

Comment: In other words, you’re “asking for a friend”?

Answer (score 2):

There is no authentic report on the specific punishment for masturbation in the hereafter. It is a sin like many other sins and one can repent from it and it may be punished or may be forgiven dependent on the will of Allah.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific punishment for masturbation in this life or the hereafter. It’s not like Zina. However, that doesn’t mean it won’t be considered a sin.

What your friend did is wise. It was better for him to masturbate on his own (despite it being it a sin) than go one step further and commit Zina which is an even bigger sin.

However, like all sins, Allah forgives all sins.
Repent and Allah will forgive!

If you don’t, on the day of judgement, your hands will speak, confronting Allah about the things you/your friend did with their own hands. They will testify against you.

> “On the Day when their tongues, their hands, and their legs or feet will bear witness against them as to what they used to do.” 
> —Quran 24:24

So please, repentance is the best advice!
Come back to Allah!